# Suppose that $P(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $n$ such that $P(k)=\frac{k^{2}}{k^{3}+1}$ for $k=0,1,\ldots,n$, find the value of $P(n+1)$

Tags: polynomials

Suppose that $P(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $n$ such that $P(k)=\dfrac{k^{2}}{k^{3}+1}$ for $k=0,1,\ldots,n$. Find the value of $P(n+1)$

I tried by making a $f(x) = (x^3+1) P(x) - x^2$. But this equation will have $n+3$ roots, out of which $n+1$ will be $0,1,2,...,n$. What about the other two roots? Can we simplify $x^2 \over x^3+1$ more to help?

Comment: Please include the question in the body, and not just in the title

Comment: Sorry, I am new here. Won't commit the same mistake again.

Comment: Lagrange interpolation?

Comment: It's in a 9th class book. Actually, I am a teacher, and a 9th class kid asked me this. I was stuck, didn't know how to proceed after the step I have written above.

Comment: No `\dfrac` in titles please.

Comment: @lhf how do u get that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using (Lagrange) polynomial interpolation:
\begin{align*}
P(x) &= \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{k^2}{k^3+1} \left( \prod_{j \neq k} \frac{x - j}{k-j} \right) \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{k^2}{k^3+1} \left(  \frac{x (x-1) \cdots (x - (k-1)) (x-(k+1)) \cdots (x-n) }{ k (k-1) \cdots (k-(k-1)) (k-(k+1)) \cdots (k-n)}\right) \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{k^2}{k^3+1} \left(  \frac{x (x-1) \cdots (x - (k-1)) (x-(k+1)) \cdots (x-n) }{ k! (n-k)!(-1)^{n-k} } \right) \\
\end{align*}
Substituting,
\begin{align*}
P(n+1) &= \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{k^2}{k^3+1} \left(  \frac{(n+1) (n) \cdots (n+2-k) (n-k) \cdots (1) }{ k! (n-k)!(-1)^{n-k} } \right) \\ 
&=  \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{k^2}{k^3+1} \left(  \frac{(n+1)!}{ k! (n-k)!(-1)^{n-k} (n+1-k)} \right) \\ 
&=  \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^{k-n} \frac{k^2}{k^3+1} {n+1 \choose k} \\
\end{align*}

Comment: +1. That was the first it came to my mind: The straightforward approach.

Answer (score 4):

If $p(x)$ is a polynomial with degree $\leq n$ and $\delta$ is the forward difference operator, $(\delta p)(x)=p(x+1)-p(x)$, we have that
$$ \left(\delta^{n+1}p\right)(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{n+1}\binom{n+1}{k}(-1)^k\,p(x+k) = 0\tag{1} $$
hence in our case 
$$ P(n+1)=(-1)^n\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n+1}{k}(-1)^k \frac{k^2}{k^3+1}.\tag{2} $$

---

**Addendum**. Can we compute a closed form for the RHS of (2)? With a bit of patience, yes.
Let $\omega=\exp\left(\frac{\pi i}{3}\right)=\frac{1+i\sqrt{3}}{2}$. By partial fraction decomposition we have
$$ \frac{k^2}{k+1} = \frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{1}{k+1}+\frac{1}{k-\omega}+\frac{1}{k-\overline{\omega}}\right)\tag{3} $$
and since $\frac{1}{k+1}=\int_{0}^{1}x^k\,dx$,
$$ \sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n+1}{k}\frac{(-1)^k}{k+1} = \frac{1+(-1)^n}{n+2}\tag{4} $$

$$ \sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n+1}{k}(-1)^k\left(\frac{1}{k-\omega}+\frac{1}{k-\overline{\omega}}\right)\\ = \frac{(-1)^n(2n+1)}{n^2+n+1}+\underbrace{2\,\text{Re}\,B\left(n+2,\frac{-1+i\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)}_{\text{wildly oscillating term.}}\tag{5} $$

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer

---

Let $P(x)$ be

$$P(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}{{{x(x-1)(x-2)...(x-n)}\over{k!(n-k)!(-1)^{(n-k)}(x-k)}}P(k)}$$

It satisfies $P(x) = {k^2 \over k^3 + 1}$ for $k = 0,1,...,n$.

This is gotten from using the term $x(x-1)(x-2)...(x-n) \over x-k$ to zero all the other terms, while dividing by $k!(n-k)!(-1)^{(n-k)}$ makes the fraction $1$.

Then

$$P(n+1)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}{{(n+1)!\over {k!(n-k)!(-1)^{(n-k)}(n+1-k)}}P(k)}$$

$$=\sum_{k=0}^{n}{{(n+1)!\over {k!(n+1-k)!}}(-1)^{(n-k)}P(k)}$$

$$=\sum_{k=0}^{n}{{n+1 \choose k}(-1)^{(n-k)}P(k)}$$

$$=\sum_{k=0}^{n}{{n+1 \choose k}(-1)^{(n-k)}{k^2 \over k^3+1}}$$

Answer (score 0):

Assuming to be working in complex case, we can write $f(x) = cx.(x-1)..(x-n)(x-a_1)(x-a_2) $. Now put the value of  $x$ as the roots of $x^3 +1$. you shall get three equations solve them to get your three constants.

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: put x = -1, then you see you get an equation similarly put the other roots of x^3 +1 in the equation then on again you get an equation.